# How to handle fling and single touch exclusively with a custom gesture listener

Tags: android, android-listview, gesture

I have a ListView and I created a custom gesture listener to handle fling touches. I had to override onSingleTapConfirmed to let the listener handle the item touch as well. Unfortunately, if I touch an item, it gets highlighted but doesn't get pushed.

I use the following code in the activity:

```
ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new CustomGestureListener(this));
if (listView != null)
 listView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
  {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
     {
    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
       return false;
         }
       return true;
            }
          });
```

In the CustomGestureListener:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event)
  {
    ListView listView=(ListView)((InfoActivity)context).findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onSingleTapUp(event);
  }
```

Also, If I use scroll like this, there is no scroll:

```
@Override
  public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
  {        
    return super.onScroll(e1,e2,distanceX,distanceY);
  }
```

What should I set to let my listview items get clicked, get scrolled and let fling work, too?

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to handle fling and click exclusively: if the user touches an item, let the item get clicked and start another activity. If the user uses fling, I start an animation. Right now, when a fling occurs, half of the animation is played, then the other activity starts. If I press Back, the other half of the animation is played. I want them to be called according to the movement.

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
ListView lv = new ListView(this);
ArrayAdapter<String> a = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    a.add("item " + i);
}
SimpleOnGestureListener listener = new SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSingleTapConfirmed ");
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onFling velocity x " + velocityX);
        Log.d(TAG, "onFling velocity y " + velocityY);
        return false;
    }
};
final GestureDetector gd = new GestureDetector(listener);
OnTouchListener l = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gd.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
};
lv.setOnTouchListener(l);
lv.setAdapter(a);
setContentView(lv);
```

Comment: If I change my code to return gd.onTouchEvent, and return false in my onSingleTapConfirmed, I get both event fired. I want them exclusively.Any idea?

Comment: not sure what you nean. i dont see both events to be fired at the same time

Comment: Check my comment at the starting post.

Comment: if you want scroll as well then override onScroll in my SimpleOnGestureListener

Comment: The problem is that fling and click happens the same time. I want fling OR click reaction. It seems they don't exist without each other.

Comment: and if you say that tap and fling events exist at the same time run my code and post the output of logcat -v time